Trying to replace fluorescent lights with LED retrofits
I recently bought this vintage light up store display, and I'm trying to replace the old F36T12-CW fluorescent lamps with LED retrofits, but they don't seem to be working. I don't know much about lighting fixtures or ballasts, so bear with me.
Imgur gallery of my fixture: https://imgur.com/a/SFbyM7J
From my reading, I think I should be able to use ‘type A’ led lamps as drop-in replacements without having to rewire/bypass the ballast, so I snagged two of these (same base, length, color temp, and ‘type A’): https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-GE-LED-30W-T8A-3FT-CCT/5001967175
The original ballast still works with its original fluorescent lamps (pic #1), but only with both lamps installed. If only one lamp is installed, one side will run very dimly (pic #2), and the other not at all (pic #3). With both LED lamps installed, one will light very dimly and the other not at all (pic #4), and if only one LED is installed neither side will light.
I opened the housing to check the ballast but the label is very deteriorated. It looks like some moisture got in, though most of this is dirt not rust. Maybe the ballast is faulty? Should I bypass it and get some ‘type B’ lamps like these instead?
https://www.homedepot.com/p/toggled-36-in-12-Watt-Daylight-5000K-T8-T12-Linear-Tube-LED-Light-Bulb-E312-50310/205622698
Thanks for your help!

Do you want to preserve it, or just to make it work?

I originally did want to try to preserve as much of it as possible, but at the end of the day yes I just want it to work. If it's simpler/better/whatever to just bypass the ballast, then so be it. I am curious why the bulbs I bought don't work though/where I went wrong. Also, why doesn't the ballast work with just one lamp installed, when the sockets are wired independently?

Is there a distinction between "display" and "fixture?"

I took the fixture out of the display - that's what the pictures are of in my above imgur gallery. I suppose in the long run it doesn't really matter if the ballast isn't original/intact

Your bulb is a T8 but the original ballast is T12, perhaps that's your issue?

I had thought T8/12 were interchangeable and the only difference was diameter, maybe this is incorrect

Most of the reviews for those bulbs on Lowe's site are negative and speak to similar problems to what you're experiencing. Maybe try a different brand and get T12 lamps this time. I think that the difference between T8 and T12 bulbs mostly refer to the diameter of the bulb, but there may be an issue with the contact pins fitting the fixtures correctly too. Might be an issue with a vintage fixture and modern bulbs not quite fitting correctly if there's been some "creep" in the specifications or tolerances over the years.

@gnicko even the single terminal version of those particular bulbs are finicky crap. I think it's just a bad design.

The behavior your are seeing with the original ballast and fluorescent tubes is quite normal. Many older magnetic ballasts will not run properly with a single lamp installed of the two.
Ballast compatibility is tricky. Type A lamps work with the ballast in place most of the time, but certainly not in all cases. They are also noticeably less efficient due to losses in the ballast.
If you want this to be LED and you are OK with rewiring the fixture to use a Type B lamp, do it. To get it to work as Type A given the symptoms you have described, you will probably need to replace the ballast. At that point you're doing enough wiring and straying enough away from originality that I believe it makes sense to just go with the simpler Type B lamps.

Side note outside of the question as it's shopping advice: I had no end of trouble trying to use that brand of Type A lamps with old magnetic ballasts last year, and eventually gave up and switched to the other brand you linked with ballast bypass, which worked perfectly.

Thanks on both counts, seems to be the general consensus. I've got some Type B's coming, we'll see what happens
